# Migrated a database to mySQL 8.0.17, unable to upgrade or start service

Tags: mysql, migration

I recently setup a new host with mySQL ver 8.0.17 and moved an old mySQL database (ver 5.1.73) to it using `mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases > somefile.sql` and then importing it with `mysql -u root -p < /somefile.sql` . Right now, I am unable to start `mysqld` and am unable to run an update to fix the tables.

I have attempted to run a mysql upgrade as mentioned in the log, but it doesn't seem to help, or im doing it wrong. Initially I ran `mysql_upgrade` but that feature is deprecated so instead I ran `mysqld --upgrade=AUTO` and still am having issues with the service starting up. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the output from mysqld.log:

```
2020-02-07T01:09:23.054386Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2020-02-07T01:09:23.056223Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.17) starting as process 1533
2020-02-07T01:09:24.005561Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010727] [Server] System table 'plugin' is expected to be transactional.
2020-02-07T01:09:24.188459Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206417Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010929] [Server] Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.user].
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206431Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010929] [Server] Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.db].
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206442Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010929] [Server] Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.tables_priv].
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206466Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010929] [Server] Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.columns_priv].
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206486Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010929] [Server] Storage engine 'MyISAM' does not support system tables. [mysql.procs_priv].
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206719Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013143] [Server] Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 51, found 39. The table is probably corrupted
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206740Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.db. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206762Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.db. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206799Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.tables_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206818Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.tables_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206834Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.tables_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206853Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.columns_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206876Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.columns_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206892Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.procs_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206912Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.procs_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-02-07T01:09:24.206942Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.procs_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-02-07T01:09:24.207159Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010316] [Server] Fatal error: Could not read the column 'authentication_string' from table 'mysql.user'. Please perform the MySQL upgrade procedure.
2020-02-07T01:09:24.207286Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010952] [Server] The privilege system failed to initialize correctly. For complete instructions on how to upgrade MySQL to a new version please see the 'Upgrading MySQL' section from the MySQL manual.
2020-02-07T01:09:24.208023Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-02-07T01:09:25.468177Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.17)  Source distribution.
```

Comment: Your main issue was to `--all-databases` and later not skip the imported the system (mysql db) tables. MySQL 5 and 8 have differed so much that you cannot do an export and import of the system tables (it is possible to migrate things like accounts, but requires some transformation).

Comment: There is an option to force mysql to run mysql_upgrade. e.g. `mysqld --upgrade=FORCE`

Comment: See if you can load your data into 5.7.  Then upgrade-in-place to 8.0

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you are pointed to the right directory in you configuration/settings files - /usr/share/mysql[-8.0]
Then use command

```
mysqld --upgrade=FORCE
```

This worked for me.